# Attempt to present "ChatController" on "RoomViewController" which is already presenting "ConfirmUser"

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, modal-dialog

I am trying to present ChatController after dismissing ConfirmUser but I get this warning:

> Attempt to present ChatController on RoomViewController (from RoomViewController) which is already presenting ConfirmUser.

This is my code:

```
confirmPopup.dismiss(animated: false, completion: { [self] in
    dialogIsShowing = false
            
    let story = UIStoryboard(name: "Chat", bundle: nil)
    let chat = story.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "chat_controller") as? ChatController
    chat?.roomCreator = byUser
            
    controller!.present(chat!, animated: true, completion: nil)
})
```

Comment: If `animated` is `true`, does it work? I'm wondering since sometimes when animation is set to true/false in other method, behavior might differs...

Comment: You probably muddled your view controllers: what is `controller`? You call `dismiss`  for `confirmPopup`, then call `controller.present` - is confirmPopup presenting anything? Should it dismiss the presented view controller of `controller` as a weird side effect?

Comment: @Larme `animate = true` is not working

Comment: @CouchDeveloper `controller` is the parent ViewController that is presenting `confirmPopup`and I want to present `chat` at the same ViewController as `confirmPopup` after dismising it

Comment: If a VC A presents a VC B, and VC B presents VC C (A -> B -> C) and you call B.dismiss, it dismisses C (only). If you call A.dismiss it dismisses B and C, while animating C. If you call C.dismiss, it will internally call B.dismiss.

Comment: Wrap your presentation in `DispatchQueue.main.async`.

Answer (score 0):

You are presenting the chat controller before the confirmPopup is dismissed. The completion which the dismiss method is taking is being called before the dismiss operation is finished I guess.
You have to do it like this:

```
confirmPopup.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)

dialogIsShowing = false            
let story = UIStoryboard(name: "Chat", bundle: nil)
let chat = story.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "chat_controller") as? ChatController
chat?.roomCreator = byUser
            
controller!.present(chat!, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: The code is done in the completion, so it should be finished, see https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621505-dismiss

Comment: Thankyou @Larme. Is it still giving the same warning Besart ?

Comment: @Amais Sheikh yes still the same  warning

Comment: @Besart cross check whether the controller is presenting something or not, at the time when you are calling present for ChatController.